# convergence in probability is equivalent to convergence in this metric

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\mathcal{L}_0(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be the space of all real random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Then I have showed that $\rho(X,Y)=E[|X-Y|/(1+|X-Y|)]$ is a metric on $\mathcal{L}_0$. I also proved that $X_n\xrightarrow{P}X$ implies that $\rho(X_n,X)\rightarrow0$, by using the fact that $|X-Y|/(1+|X-Y|)$ is bounded by $1$ and Dominated Convergence Theorem. However I can't prove the converse. That is I need to prove $\rho(X_n,X)\rightarrow 0$ implies $X_n\xrightarrow{P}X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon\gt 0$ and define $A_n:=\{|X_n-X|\gt \varepsilon\}$.
Since $t\mapsto \frac t{1+t}$ is increasing,
$$\mathbb P(A_n)\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\mathbb E\left(\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|}\right)=\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\rho(X_n,X).$$